# Editing code from javascript onclick to jquery tap to work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, tap

I've got this working code (on desktop):

```
<ul class="center" style="width:100%;margin:auto">
    <li id="mountain" class="mobileIcons" onclick="openLandscape()"><a class="sliderHash small-caps bold" href="#landscaping">
        <p class="sliderIcon icon-mountains"></p>
        <p class="sliderText sticky">Landscaping</p></a></li>
    <li id="apple" class="mobileIcons" onclick="openEdible()"><a class="sliderHash small-caps bold" href="#edible">
        <p class="sliderIcon icon-apple"></p>
        <p class="sliderText sticky">Edible&nbsp;Accents</p></a></li>
    <li id="android" class="mobileIcons" onclick="openPests()"><a class="sliderHash small-caps bold" href="#pests">
        <p class="sliderIcon icon-android"></p>
        <p class="sliderText sticky">Pests</p></a></li>
    <li id="shopping-cart" class="mobileIcons" onclick="openProducts()"><a class="sliderHash small-caps bold" href="#products">
        <p class="sliderIcon icon-shopping-cart"></p>
        <p class="sliderText sticky">Products</p></a></li>
    <li id="info-circled" class="mobileIcons" onclick="openInfo()"><a class="sliderHash small-caps bold" href="?info=about">
        <p class="sliderIcon icon-info-circled"></p>
        <p class="sliderText sticky">About</p></a></li></ul>
```

with this script:

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("landscapeSlider").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("edibleSlider").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("pestsSlider").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("productsSlider").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("infoSlider").style.height = "0";
}
function openLandscape() {closeNav(); document.getElementById("landscapeSlider").style.height = "100%"}
function openEdible() {closeNav(); document.getElementById("edibleSlider").style.height = "100%"}
function openPests() {closeNav(); document.getElementById("pestsSlider").style.height = "100%"}
function openProducts() {closeNav(); document.getElementById("productsSlider").style.height = "100%"}
function openInfo() {closeNav(); document.getElementById("infoSlider").style.height = "100%"}
```

The code doesn't work on mobile though. I take it that it's because mobile doesn't have the onclick function so I'm attempting to translate it to jquery which shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm new ...

I added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the head and have

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mobileIcons').on('tap',function( openLandscape ) {}
    }
</script>
```

above the html. I'm sure I'm missing some parts but am at a lost as to what. Little help would be appreciated. (I also tried adding the `cursor:pointer` attribute to the css but to no avail. Apparently, that's supposed to be a trick to get the `onclick` to work.)

Comment: `function(openLandscape)` is invalid syntax. It should be `function() { openLandscape(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Click does work on mobiles. Your issue is that you are trying to use tap and not click. Try this:

```
$('#mountain').click(openLandscape);
```